# ResourcesNotFoundException when inflate menu_actionbar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I have an xml file containing some buttons to add an ActionBar. When I try to inflate this XML, my application returns ResourcesNotFoundException. Can someone help me?

This is my xml:

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:title="Item 1"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item2"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title="Item 2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom/withText"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item3"
    android:title="Item 3"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item4"
    android:title="Item 4"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>
```

This is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_action_bar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Clean and Built your project and try.

Comment: Did you import the entire `appcompat` project into your Android project - including resource files found under `/appcompat/res/` directory?

Comment: Clean and build project works! thx..!